# Spring AOP isnt working as expected with Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-aop

I have Spring Boot 1.5.x project that I'm trying to use AOP to get Kafka Producer and Consumer as follows but none of these seem to get executed.

```java
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter({TraceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ConditionalOnClass({ProducerFactory.class, ConsumerFactory.class})
@ConditionalOnBean(Tracer.class)
public class KafkaTraceAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    KafkaTraceAdvice sleuthKafkaAspect(Tracer tracer) {
        return new KafkaTraceAdvice(tracer);
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class KafkaTraceAdvice {
    public KafkaTraceAdvice(final Tracer tracer) {
        // Wraps Sleuth tracer
        this.kafkaClientTracing = KafkaClientTracing.create(tracer);
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory.createProducer(..))")
    private void producerFactory() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory.createConsumer())")
    private void consumerFactory() {
    }

    @Around("producerFactory()")
    public Object wrapProducerFactory(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Producer producer = (Producer) pjp.proceed();
        return this.kafkaClientTracing.producer(producer);
    }

    @Around("consumerFactory()")
    public Object wrapConsumerFactory(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Consumer consumer = (Consumer) pjp.proceed();
        return this.kafkaClientTracing.consumer(consumer);
    }
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
public final class KafkaClientTracing {
    public <K, V> Consumer<K, V> consumer(Consumer<K, V> consumer) {
        if (consumer == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("consumer == null");
        }
        // Do something with consumer
    }

    public <K, V> Producer<K, V> producer(Producer<K, V> producer) {
        if (producer == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("producer == null");
        }
        // Do something with producer
    }
}
```

I can see events being produced and consumed but none of these aspects are reached. Any idea what could be causing this ?

Essential Im trying to achieve the same functionality as [TraceMessagingAutoConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/2.2.x/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/TraceMessagingAutoConfiguration.java#L275) but with Spring Boot 1.5.x. Is there anything obvious I have missed ?

Comment: From the code shared it is not clear if `KafkaClientTracking` instance is a spring container managed bean , same goes for `Consumer` and `Producer` instances. Could you please clarify the same ?

Comment: @R.G Ive used `@Configurable` on `KafkaClientTracking` and both `Consumer` `Producer` kafka implementations

Comment: Can you confirm if `KafkaTraceAdvice` registered as a spring bean ? The logs during startup would show if this bean is picked up correctly.

Comment: FYI, Spring versions less than 2.2.x are no longer supported.

Comment: @GaryRussell realize that. This is for some legacy services we will eventually migrate across. But that will take time so this is going to be an intermediate step until we do so.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ideally a Maven project, on GitHub, in order to make the problem reproducible. I guess you would get an answer pretty quickly, either from myself or someone else.

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex. Working through one at the moment which il be able to flick over.

Comment: Maybe you have solved your problem in the meantime. If so, please write an answer by yourself in order to enlighten everyone. Otherwise, the MCVE would still be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate everyones help on this first of all.

Managed to solve the issue with the following on Spring Boot 1.5.x,

```java
public class KafkaTraceAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public KafkaTraceInterceptor sleuthKafkaAspect(Tracer tracer) {
        KafkaTraceInterceptor kafkaTraceInterceptor = Aspects.aspectOf(KafkaTraceInterceptor.class);
        kafkaTraceInterceptor.setKafkaTracing(KafkaClientTracing.create(tracer));
        return kafkaTraceInterceptor;
    }
}
```

And interceptor

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class KafkaTraceInterceptor {

    private KafkaClientTracing kafkaTracing;

    public void setKafkaTracing(KafkaClientTracing kafkaTracing) {
        this.kafkaTracing = kafkaTracing;
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory.createProducer(..))")
    public void anyProducerFactory() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory.createConsumer(..))")
    public void anyConsumerFactory() {
    }

    @Around("anyProducerFactory()")
    public Object wrapProducerFactory(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Producer producer = (Producer) pjp.proceed();
        if (this.kafkaTracing != null) {
            return this.kafkaTracing.producer(producer);
        }
        return producer;
    }

    @Around("anyConsumerFactory()")
    public Object wrapConsumerFactory(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Consumer consumer = (Consumer) pjp.proceed();
        if (this.kafkaTracing != null) {
            return this.kafkaTracing.consumer(consumer);
        }
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

And the Sleuth `Tracer` wrapper,

```java
@Component
public final class KafkaClientTracing {

    public static KafkaClientTracing create(Tracer tracer) {
        return new KafkaClientTracing.Builder(tracer).build();
    }

    public static final class Builder {

        final Tracer tracer;

        Builder(Tracer tracer) {
            if (tracer == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("tracer == null");
            }
            this.tracer = tracer;
        }

        public KafkaClientTracing build() {
            return new KafkaClientTracing(this);
        }
    }

    private final Tracer tracer;

    public Tracer getTracer() {
        return tracer;
    }

    public KafkaClientTracing(KafkaClientTracing.Builder builder) {
        this.tracer = builder.tracer;
    }

    public <K, V> Consumer<K, V> consumer(Consumer<K, V> consumer) {
        if (consumer == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("consumer == null");
        }
        return new TracingConsumer<>(consumer, this);
    }

    public <K, V> Producer<K, V> producer(Producer<K, V> producer) {
        if (producer == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("producer == null");
        }
        return new TracingProducer<>(producer, this);
    }
}
```

And then I execute with `-javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar`

Comment: Hm, if you use the `aspectjweaver` Java agent, it means that you actually do not use Spring AOP, but regular AspectJ. Then I would edit your question tags to read _aspectj_ rather than _spring-aop_ (or maybe both). Are you sure the AspectJ Weaver is active, i.e. you also provided `aop.xml` for Aspect? Then the aspect would not have to be a `@Component` in order to work correctly. Or do you maybe use Spring AOP after all and the project would also work without the Java agent? Hard to say, not enough information in your answer.

Comment: Yeah I dont think `@Component` was necessary. The reason I switched to using aspectjweaver was that I couldnt get Spring AOP going. Perhaps this is a limitation in the version of AOP I was using with SB 1.5. Afaik if Spring AOP under the hood it will use the spring agent in the runtime instead of aspectjweaver ? But in my case I need to aspectjweaver to weave and run the code.

Comment: Spring AOP should work for your use case, as long as your `ProducerFactory` and `ConsumerFactory` implementations are Spring beans/components. Only if you want to target classes which are not Spring-managed, you need AspectJ.